# Attempting to make a photo slide

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm quite new to Python. I'm trying to update the image periodically. I've searched around but I'm still struggling to make this work how I want. I'm just going to paste the whole .py file I have.

Right now, It seems as though it's incrementing properly. I know the `__init__` function in the Window class gets run only once so it is iterating but not actually updating the `ImageTk.PhotoImage` object. I think it has to do with my `resize_image` function because in `change_photo` when I try to configure the label to the new image with the updated index, I just get a blank image after the allotted time.

I just think I'm not quite on the right track and need a nudge in the right direction here. Thank you

```
class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        self.photos = getPhotos()
        self.index = 0

        self.image = Image.open(path + self.photos[self.index])

        self.img_copy = self.image.copy()

        self.imageTK = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.label = Label(self, image=self.imageTK)
        self.label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        self.label.bind('<Configure>', self.resize_image)


    def resize_image(self, event):
        orig_width = self.image.width
        orig_height = self.image.height

        new_width = updateWidth(orig_width, orig_height)

        new_height = event.height

        self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))

        self.imageTK = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.label.configure(image=self.imageTK)

    def change_photo(self):
        if self.index == (len(self.photos) - 1):
            self.index = 0
        else:
            self.index += 1
            self.label.configure(image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path + self.photos[self.index])))
            root.after(1000, self.change_photo)


app = Window(root)
app.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

app.change_photo()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: can u make it reproducible ? otherwise it's really  hard to find out.

Comment: You said you pasted the whole file, but there are no imports and `getPhotos` and `root` are not defined.